# str.startswith() not working as I intended

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I can't see why this won't work. I am performing lstrip() on the string being passed to the function, and trying to see if it starts with """. For some reason, it gets caught in an infinite loop

```
def find_comment(infile, line):

    line_t = line.lstrip()
    if not line_t.startswith('"""') and not line_t.startswith('#'):
        print (line, end = '')
        return line

    elif line.lstrip().startswith('"""'):
            while True:
                if line.rstrip().endswith('"""'):
                    line = infile.readline()
                    find_comment(infile, line)
                else:
                    line = infile.readline()
    else:
        line = infile.readline()
        find_comment(infile, line)
```

And my output:

```
Enter the file name: test.txt
import re
def count_loc(infile):
```

Here is the top of the file i am reading in for reference:

```
    import re

    def count_loc(infile):
        """ Receives a file and then returns the amount
            of actual lines of code by not counting commented
            or blank lines """

        loc = 0
        func_records = {}
        for line in infile:
        (...)
```

Comment: Duplicate and repost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927584/str-startswith-not-working-as-i-intended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided and exit path from the recursive loop. A return statement should do the trick.

```
    (...)
    while True:
        if line.rstrip().endswith('"""'):
            line = infile.readline()
            return find_comment(infile, line)
        else:
            line = infile.readline()
```

Comment: O man, I can't believe I forgot that. For some reason i thought that calling the function again would break the loop. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`while True` is an infinite loop.  You need to `break` once you're done.

Answer (score 1):

```
not line_t.startswith('"""') or not line_t.startswith('#')
```

This expression evaluates to True no matter what string line_t denotes. Do you want 'and' instead of 'or'? Your question isn't clear to me.

Comment: woops, yeah I changed that, but it gets stuck in an infinite loop at the while statement posted above. I updated my original post to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

```
if not line_t.startswith('"""') or not line_t.startswith('#'):
```

This `if` will always be satisfied -- either the line doesn't start with `"""`, or it doesn't start with `#` (or both).  You probably meant to use `and` where you used `or`.

Comment: yeah, that's right, however I now get stuck in the infinite while loop. But I don't know why, any insight from the source given? I updated my original post to reflect this

Comment: Maybe because your while loop says "while True" and you don't break. Just a wild guess...

Answer (score 1):

As long as lines start or end with a comment, the code below should work.

However, keep in mind that the docstrings can start or end in the middle of a line of code.

Also, you'll need to code for triple single-quotes as well as docstrings assigned to variables which aren't really comments.

Does this get you closer to an answer?

```
def count_loc(infile):
  skipping_comments = False
  loc = 0 
  for line in infile:
    # Skip one-liners
    if line.strip().startswith("#"): continue
    # Toggle multi-line comment finder: on and off
    if line.strip().startswith('"""'):
      skipping_comments = not skipping_comments
    if line.strip().endswith('"""'):
      skipping_comments = not skipping_comments
      continue
    if skipping_comments: continue
    print line,
```

Comment: Ah I forgot about the triple single quotes. This project is actually for my C++ class, but I've been trying to teach myself python at the same time and decided to the project twice. Thanks for the code, all I needed was that return statement out of the while loop.