# Python: startswith() not working as intended

Tags: python, string, list

I am writing a program that loads an external txt file of movies. This part works fine. I then have a function that searches a list of movies generated from the file. The function should print out all movies that start with the search string.

```
def startsWithSearch(movieList):

    searchString = input("Enter search string: ")

    for movie in movieList:
        if(movie.startswith(searchString) == True):
        print(movie)
```

However, no movies are printed when I enter a search string, even though there are movies in the list that start with that string.

Comment: So what is in `movieList` exactly? You don't need to do `== True`, `if` *already* tests that.

Comment: `movie.startswith()` requires an exact (case sensitive!) match at the start of a string. Without details of what you are entering and what values you are giving it in `movieList` we cannot help you figure out where the values do not match. Use `repr()` or `ascii()` to produce output that helps you debug issues like these: `print(repr(searchString))` and `print(repr(movie))` should make it much more visible how much strings actually match.

Comment: The indentation looks broken, I suppose the 'print' statement should've been indented further than the 'if'. Did you post the actual code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [str.startswith() not working as I intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929169/str-startswith-not-working-as-i-intended)

Answer (score 2):

if given correct input data your function does work as expected:

```
def startsWithSearch(movieList):

    searchString = "test4"

    for movie in movieList:
        if(movie.startswith(searchString)):
            print(movie)


startsWithSearch(["test1","testnomatch","test4","test4should","not_test4"])
```

output is:

```
test4
test4should
```

so all correct... must be your input data

i know you want a StartsWith solution as your function name says, but actually searching for movies, it is a lot more convenient, if you find any match inside the string, so if i search for "mentalist" i will find "the mentalist", then you could just use:

```
if searchString in movie:
    print(movie)
```

And as suggested by Anna to ignore case:

```
if searchString.lower() in movie.lower():
```

or even fancier with regular expressions (need `import re` at first line):

```
if re.match(".*" + searchString,movie,re.I):
```

or if you really just want match on beginning of name:

```
if re.match(searchString,movie,re.I):
```

that should be enough alternatives :)

Comment: You might also want case insensitive search; an easy way to do that would be to check 'if searchString.lower() in movie.lower():...'

Comment: @Anna added your suggestion and another regex variant

Answer (score 0):

I would think it might be that the `input()` function is returning with a new line at the end.  Try adding `searchString = searchString.strip()` after collecting the input data.
Also you might want to try converting both to lower case before comparing.

Also the line `if(movie.startswith(searchString) == True):` can just be written as `if movie.startswith(searchString):`

Comment: `input` strips the final newline on its own. That's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when I was reading from files. `startswith` was failing due to newline character which was read from file. Use `rstrip()` to remove newline character from both strings before you use `startswith` function.